# Asp.net MVC Razor: Passing Complex model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have two classes:

```
public class Sportevent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventsStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventsEnd { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Nation { get; set; }
}
```

So a Sportevent references an Address Entity.
The view for creating a Sportevent contains also the forms for the address.
The controller receives the infos, but what happens with the Address? How can I pass them or is it already contained

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EventsStart,EventsEnd, Address")] Sportevent sportevent){
...
}
```

I think the above syntax of the binding is incorrect, because Address is a complex datatype instead a primitve one, or not?
So what's the best practice for passing such complex datamodels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bind` attribute might be necessary as a security precaution if you are binding directly to the EF persistable classes.

To get rid of it, introduce ViewModels that only contain the fields that the user is allowed to change. An additional benefit is that you can put View-centric properties and methods in the ViewModel and they will not pollute your entity model (separation of concerns).

```
public class CreateSporteventViewModel
{
    // ID is not needed in create usecase because it will be assigned by EF
    public DateTime EventsStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventsEnd { get; set; }

    public CreateAddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
}

public class CreateAddressViewModel 
{
    // ID is not needed in create usecase because it will be assigned by EF

    // Example of View-centric attribute
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "Street")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    // ... other properties relevant for create view
}
```

In the View, render the `<input>` as mentioned by user7405157:

```
@model CreateSporteventViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EventsStart)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Address.Address1)
```

In the controller, create the entity model and populate it. There are libraries to facilitate this mapping step, e.g. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateSporteventViewModel viewModel){
    var persistableEvent = new Sportevent {
        EventsStart = viewModel.EventsStart,
        // ...
    };

    var persistableAddress = new Address {
       Address1 = viewModel.Address.Address1,
       // ...
    };
    persistableEvent.Address = persistableAddress;

    dbContext.Sportevents.Add(persistableEvent);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: So the solution/trick/idea of ViewModels is creating an additional Layer, which represents the model, in the views, right? The ViewModel-Data has to be converted explizit via code, right? But so I have a code duplicate.

Comment: I'm thinking about deriving the class and hidding the properties, but this would destroy the concept of separation.

Comment: Yes, there is a certain amount of replication between the ViewModel and EF Entity Model. Conversion has to be done somewhere in the code, even if you use AutoMapper you have to configure it. I don't think that deriving the ViewModel from the Entity Model would work, for example it would not be possible to hide the ID in the CreateViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `Bind` attribute at all.

Just in your view for inputs that should bind the data for `Address` in input's name attribute put `Address.ID`, `Address.Address1`, `Address.PostalCode` and so on. Default binding will do the work for you.

Comment: So my code looks like this @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Adress1, ...) and I pass the model which type is Sportevent. I like to use this Binding operation like suggested here [link](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) for preventing cross-site request forgery attacks.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think that using `Bind` attribute in this case has anything to do with cross-site request forgery attacks. For that you should put `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` inside your form and decorate your action with `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. As for the initial question the way you use `@Html.EditorFor` should be all you need (if you remove the `Bind` attribute.

Comment: Hmm. I just read the article you provided and now I know what you mean. Well, you could always just write your custom model binder I guess.

Comment: The background is that the "Include" parameter defines something like a whitelist. So overposting e.g. the ID-Parameter isn't possible. If the token is stolen then it's not possible to set this parameter.